# Acrobat rendering bug with checkboxes in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, acrobat

I use TCPDF for a dynamic form that gets generated from a table using mysql and php.   I've been using it for some time now without issue, but lately I've noticed a rendering issue that is bugging me.  At first I thought it was something in my code, but now I don't think so, and either believe it an issue with TCPDF or with acrobat...I'm leaning towards the later.

Here is what the form looks like in the browser(the section in question):
[image]

and here is what  the same PDF, downloaded and opened in Acrobat DC/Reader XI looks like:
[image]

This section is defined via the following code:

```
switch ((int)$appflags) 
{
case 0:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> DoD 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 1:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> DoD 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 2:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> DoD 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 3:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Dod 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 4:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Dod 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 5:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Dod 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 6:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Dod 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;

case 7:
    $left_column = '<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Shredding/Pulverizing<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Dod 5220.22-M<br><input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1" checked="checked" readonly="true" /> Deleting';
    break;
}


$pdf->writeHTMLCell(60, '', 24, 165, $left_column, 0, 0, 0, true, 'J', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(60, '', 124, 165, $right_column, 0, 2, 0, true, 'J', true);
```

Same code, same pdf, but when downloaded and opened in DC (latest acrobat version 2015.009.20079) there is a difference in checkbox rendering.  I uninstalled Acrobat DC, went back and installed Adobe Reader XI, same issue.   I then forwarded one of these PDFs to my Phone, opened it there...everything works.

So it works on my Android device, it works in  Chrome, only doesn't work in Desktop readers.   Is this a problem with Acrobat Reader, or is it something with the writehtml code?

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded NitroPDF, document renders fine.  I'm chalking this one up to a problem in Adobe's software.